# Table Structure for Managing a Collection with Org Table

Tags: database, emacs, spreadsheet, org-mode, org-table

I have found org tables to be very powerful and useful. I feel like I have movement, table restructuring and basic formulas down fairly well. But I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around how I should structure this for tracking large collections. Not sure if I can do this in one table or if I need multiple tables.

Say I have a business that buys and sells trading cards. There are baseball, basketball and football cards. I want to track purchase price, sale price, purchase date, sale date, average sale price, last sale price, quantity in stock, and item condition for every card sold or in stock.

Is it possible to do this in a single table or do I need multiple tables?

I'd like to track statistics such as:

"What is the average price of all football cards sold in the last six months?"

"In the last month, did I buy more basketball cards or baseball cards?

And for a more lengthy example:

"Last year I sold 4 Mickey Mantle cards. 2 in Mint condition, 1 in Excellent condition, 1 in Poor condition and 1 unsold. What percentage of Mint Mickey Mantle cards were sold last year?"

To reiterate, in org-mode can all this be accomplished within a single table? How would it be structured if say, you knew Tops only made 2000 unique cards in a particular year, would table only contain 2000 rows? (plus the header)

If it can't be accomplished in a single table, I'm just going to use a `postgres` database structured much [like the one mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590712/284194). I was really hoping there was a snazzy way to do this with org-table alone. But it looks like there are other ways to manipulate databases within emacs.

Sorry if most of this sounds like a high school math problem with no code but I'm sure most people (at least here) know what a single org table with the mentioned columns and a finite set of rows would look like.

Edit1: Can [org references](http://orgmode.org/manual/References.html) be used to link tables together to help get the results I'm looking for?

Edit2: The reason why I thought this was possible in org-mode, was because I did not think a foreign key was necessary. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7590712/284194) is a very similar example not using a foreign key. When reading about construction of spreadsheets in org-mode, foreign keys seemed to be the only obvious hurdle. Anyone have thoughts on this?

Comment: I know that this does not answer your question, but... I would not use org tables - I would use a database.

Comment: That's okay, I appreciate the response. I was thinking that if the table had a finite amount of rows, a spreadsheet with cell functions could accomplish this task. I would like this to be as DRY as possible. Nearly everything I keep track of is in org-mode and was hoping I could keep it that way. I'm starting to think this question may be more of a generic spreadsheet / database question so I'm going to add the database tag after reading your response. Thank you